# Como tratar um campo decimal sem casas após a vírgula em uma máscara jquery mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, decimal, maskmoney

Tenho um model com a seguinte definição:

```
[Display(Name = "Quantidade / Volume:")]
public Int32 RoQuantidade { set; get; }
```

Em minha *View* para preencher os dados quando vazios, ou seja, que ainda não foram gravados, usando o `maskMoney` funciona sem problemas. Eu utilizo da seguinte forma:

```
$('#RoQuantidade').maskMoney({ 
        showSymbol: false, 
        symbol: "R$", 
        decimal: ",", 
        thousands: ".", 
        allowZero: true, 
        allowNegative: false, 
        precision: 0 
});
```

Repare que eu informo que a precisão é zero, pois eu não preciso de casas decimais neste caso.

O problema começa quando vou recuperar a informação da fonte de dados. No meu `controller` eu recupero a informação assim:

```
model.RoQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(_sheet.Cells[lin, 3].value2);
```

Estou pegando a informação de uma planilha Excel, porém esse não é o problema. Acontece que o retorno para a *view* mesmo eu retirando a máscara ou tentando converter, sempre retornar da seguinte maneira:

- valor original: 30000
- Valor retornado para a *view*: 30000,00

Se utilizo o `maskMoney` da forma que coloquei acima com um parâmetro a mais que é

```
$('#Disponivel').maskMoney({ 
        showSymbol: false, 
        symbol: "R$", 
        decimal: ",", 
        thousands: ".",
        allowZero: true, 
        allowNegative: true 
}).maskMoney('mask', $('#Disponivel').val());
```

para formatar o valor retornado ele apresenta o valor: 3.000.000, pois o campo por ser decimal acrescentou os dois zeros transformando de 30 mil para 3 milhões

Já tentei alterar a definição do campo para `int32`, porém a formatação fica com problemas e na hora de gravar informa que existe erro pois não pode gravar 30,000 (repare que ele mudou mesmo com a definição correta o ponto pela virgula).

Já tentei usar outros plugins jquery como o maskedit, mas não consegui, principalmente quando do retorno da informação.

Se vocês tiverem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer para preencher o valor formatado, gravar a informação sem formatação, recuperar a informação sem formatação e apresentar de forma formatada, não tem problema algum mudar de `decimal` para outro tipo, só preciso fazer com que ele respeite a situação acima que descrevi.

Deixarei algumas imagens abaixo que ilustram o que estou dizendo:

[image: Alert na view para mostrar o valor vindo como 30000]

[image: Quando eu defino como int32 a máscara fica assim]

[image: Quando eu defino como decimal o alert mostra o retorno dessa forma]

[image: Quando eu defino como decimal o maskMoney acaba mostrando dessa forma]

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Primeiro, porque você está tratando um inteiro como `decimal`, salvando como `decimal` e ainda assim querendo que o campo se comporte como inteiro em tela. Obviamente não vai funcionar direito.

Se o campo não terá casas após a vírgula, apenas o uso de `decimal` já é errado, **por mais que o campo esteja em Reais**, que, em teoria, pede a casa dos centavos. É por isso que o campo se chama `decimal`: porque **tem casas decimais**.

Aqui, por exemplo, a própria conversão é para inteiro:

```
model.RoQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(_sheet.Cells[lin, 3].value2);
```

Se você passa `30000` para o *Controller* e o campo é `decimal`, obviamente que o *MdelBinder* vai esperar pelo menos uma casa decimal (o normal são duas). Não há qualquer problema com o `mask-money`: é a definição de variáveis que está incorreta.